# How not to show dropdown menu if the @ char is within the curly brackets in a string using javascript or react?

Tags: javascript

i want to not to show the dropdown menu if the @ character is within curly brackets in a string.

what i am trying to do?
when user types in @ char in input field, dropdown menu is shown if based on the string typed in after @ char and cursor position.

now there might be case where the @ char could be within the curly brackets say i have string in input field like below

"i am {9@somechar}"

now user types in @ between some and char words like below

"i am {9@some@char}" and the cursor is at the second @char in the string now i dont want to show the dropdown menu in that case how can i do it.

below is what i have tried.

```
class Showdropdown extends React.PureComponent {
    input_change = (event) => {
        const {value} = event.target;
        this.setState({value: value});
        this.handle_at_character(value);
    };
    handle_at_character = (value) => {
        const str_to_cursor_pos = value.substring(0, 
        event.target.selectionStart);
        const str_after_at = value.includes('@') && 
        str_to_cursor_pos.substring(str_to_cursor_pos.lastIndexOf( 
       '@') + 1);
    if (str_after_at !== false && (str_after_at.match(/\s/g)||[]).length 
        <= 1) {
        const show = menuitems.filter(menuitem => {
            return menuitem.toLowerCase().includes(str_after_at);
        });
        this.setState({show});
    } else {
        this.setState({show: []});
    }
};
    render = () => {
        return (
            <input
                onChange={this.input_change}
                value={this.state.value}/>
            {this.state.show && <Dropdown />}
         )
     }
 }
```

the above code also shows dropdown if @ is within curly brackets. how can i fix this. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: For one thing, you probably want `onInput={this.input_change}`. The "input" event fires every time there's a change in the input. The "change" event, despite its name, doesn't fire as often, only when input focus changes, or the user presses Tab or Enter.

Answer (score 0):

In your code show with [] value was true in this.state.show &&... case.
Keep it simple. Use undefined instead:

```
this.setState({ show });
} else {
    this.setState({ show: undefined });
```

When show is undefined, next component will be hidden

```
{ this.state.show && <Dropdown /> }
```